# How do I make an heterogeneous list in Haskell? (originally in Java)

Tags: haskell, typeclass

How to convert following Java implementation into Haskell?

The major purpose here is having a list that contains various elements which are sub-type of a particular interface.
I tried to make a Haskell version below but fail to meet my purpose. 
The point here is `xs` has type `[Bar]` rather than `Foo a => [a]`

Do that mean Haskell can not do this and shall I think in another way?

**Java**

```java
interface Foo {
    void bar ();
}

public class Bar1 implements Foo {
    @Override
    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("I am bar 1 class");
    }   
}

public class Bar2 implements Foo {
    @Override
    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("I am bar 2 class");
    }   
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // The major purpose here is having a list 
    // that contains elements which are sub-type of "Foo"
    List<Foo> ys = new ArrayList<Foo>();

    Foo e1 = new Bar1();
    Foo e2 = new Bar2();

    ys.add(e1);
    ys.add(e2);

    for (Foo foo : ys) {
        foo.bar();
    }
}
```

**Haskell**

```
class Foo a where
  bar :: a -> IO ()

data Bar = Bar1 | Bar2

instance Foo Bar where
  bar Bar1 = print "I am Bar1"
  bar Bar2 = print "I am Bar2"

--xs :: Foo a => [a]
xs :: [Bar]
xs = [Bar1, Bar2]

main :: IO ()
main = mapM_ bar xs
```

Comment: Your implementation in Haskell looks fine to me. I'd even go as far and say that the proper translation is: `bar1 = "I am Bar1"; bar2 = "I am Bar2"; xs = [bar1, bar2]; main = mapM_ putStrLn xs`

Comment: Actually the point here is that to have a list of elements which implement particular interface.

Comment: Yes, but that interface is (in this case) of type `String`, or perhaps `IO String`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simple answer: [*don't*! Haskell is not an OO language, and it's not much good pretending it is and just trying to translate inheritance patterns to a mixture of type classes and ADTs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184286/object-oriented-programming-in-haskell/20188103#20188103).

Your `List<Foo>` in Java is quite substantially different from a `Foo a => [a]` in Haskell: such a signature actually means `forall a . Foo a => [a]`. The `a` is basically an extra argument to the function, i.e. it can be chosen from the outside what particular `Foo` instance is used here.

Quite the opposite in Java: there you don't have any control of what types are in the list at all, only know that they implement the `Foo` interface. In Haskell, we call this an *existential type*, and generally avoid it because it's stupid. Ok, you disagree – sorry, you're wrong!
...No, seriously, if you have such an existential list, the only thing you can ever do<sup>1</sup> is execute the `bar` action. *Well, then why not simply put that action in the list right away*! `IO()` actions are values just like anything else (they aren't functions; anyway those can be put in lists just as well). I'd write your program

```
xs :: [IO ()]
xs = [bar Bar1, bar Bar2]
```

---

That said, if you absolutely insist you can have existential lists in Haskell as well:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data AFoo = forall a. Foo a => AFoo a

xs :: [AFoo]
xs = [AFoo Bar1, AFoo Bar2]

main = mapM_ (\(AFoo f) -> bar f) xs
```

---

As this has become quite a rant: I do acknoledge that OO style is for some applications more convenient than Haskell's functional style. And existentials do have their valid use cases (though, like chunksOf 50, I rather prefer to write them as [GADTs](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GADTs_for_dummies)). Only, for lots of problems Haskell allows for far more concise, powerful, general, yet in many ways simpler solutions than the "if all you have's a hammer..." inheritance you'd use in OO programming, so before using existentials you should get a proper feeling for Haskell's "native" features.

---

<sup>1</sup>Yeah, I know you can also do "typesafe dynamic casts" etc. in Java. In Haskell, there's the `Typeable` class for this kind of stuff. But you might as well use a dynamic language right away if you take such paths.

Comment: With XConstraintKinds one may perform few interesting tricks. But generally you're right about uselessness of such OOP simulation.

Comment: GADTs are a prettier way of doing existential quantification, but list of `IO()` or a data type representing everything you want is best, like you say, yes.

Comment: Using existentials isn't always wrong, it's just usually wrong.

Comment: Thanks your explanation. I'm "shaped out" by Java and I do want more functional thinking!

Comment: The only "painful" thing about writing `xs = [bar Bar1, bar Bar2]` is that I need type `bar` function many times while I have lots of Bar (Bar3, Bar4,etc). I'm wondering to design in another way or I have to use existentials type at such case?

Comment: You will never escape the need to convert each value from its distinct type to a common type, because `[]` can only contain one type, and your `Foo` values are of different type. (I assume you really mean that you have different types `Bar`, `Baz`, etc that satisfy  `instance Foo`).  You have to convert/wrap each type to the common type *somewhere* in your program.   In Java, an interface can stand in for a concrete type. In Haskell, there no such construct that can stand in for values of different types at the same time in one expression. http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/OOP_vs_type_classes

Comment: This could be less ranty.

Comment: @DavidGiven: I never denied it.

Answer (score 9):

Your translation has an important drawback. Whereas in your Java version, you could easily add a `Bar3` that also supports the `Foo` interface, you cannot easily achieve the same without touching the `Bar` type in the Haskell version. So this is rather not the version you are looking for.

In a way you are looking for a heterogeneous list. [Other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7787317/3168666) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13672482/3168666) are covering this aspect already.

What you really want though is to get rid of the need of a type class altogether. Instead have a data type representing the behavior of `Foo`:

```
data Foo = Foo { bar :: IO () }
```

Then you can construct your list of object satisfying the `Foo` interface as a `[Foo]`.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is very similar to the existential `data Boxy = forall a. Classy a => Boxy a` since typeclasses are eventually transformed into records.

Answer (score 7):

This is possible but probably not desirable. There is such language extension as 'existential types' that allows dynamic polymorphism.

The idea of existential type is following:

```
data Foo = Foo a
```

Note that type variable "a" doesn't appear on the left side of ADT declaration. Simple example of possible implementation of dynamic polymorphic list and map function:

```
{-# LANGUAGE UnicodeSyntax, Rank2Types, GADTs, ConstraintKinds #-}

import Data.Constraint

-- List datatype:
data PList α where
   Nil  ∷ PList α
   (:*) ∷ α a ⇒ a → PList α → PList α

infixr 6 :*

-- Polymorphic map:
pmap ∷ (∀ a. α a ⇒ a → b) → PList α → [b]
pmap _ Nil      = []
pmap f (a :* t) = f a : pmap f t

main = let
        -- Declare list of arbitrary typed values with overloaded instance Show:
        l ∷ PList Show
        l = "Truly polymorphic list " :* 'a' :* 1 :* (2, 2) :* Nil
    in do
        -- Map show to list:
        print $ pmap show l
```

Output:

```
["\"Truly polymorphic list \"","'a'","1","(2,2)"]
```

Another example using this technique:

```
class Show a ⇒ Named a where
    name ∷ a → String

instance Named Int where
    name a = "I'm Int and my value is " ++ show a

instance Named Char where
    name a = "I'm Char and my value is " ++ show a

 main = let
        -- Declare list of arbitrary typed values with overloaded instance Named:
        l2 :: PList Named
        l2 = 'a' :* (1 ∷ Int) :* Nil
    in do 
        print $ pmap name l2
        print $ pmap show l2
```

Output:

```
["I'm Char and my value is 'a'","I'm Int and my value is 1"]
["'a'","1"]
```

Comment: This would be another impl. Thanks. Is the `Foo` named "phatom type"?

Answer (score 2):

To migrate from OOP to Haskell, read this:

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/OOP_vs_type_classes